# Worker isn't populating some apps on Django

Tags: python, django, celery, worker

The worker from my django project isn't detecting some apps but other yes. All of them are in INSTALLED_APPS. And thats makeing it restarting endless. What could be it?

here is the directory structure:

```
-project
  -worker
    -pycache
    -__init__.py
    -celery.py
    -tasks.py
```

The traceback below is getting error on bootstrapform, if I take off that from installed apps, the next module go to the traceback which is crispy_forms and so on.
here is the traceback:

```html
Checking for celery...   OK

Starting worker using broker at redis://broker

Checking for celery...   OK

Starting worker using broker at redis://broker

    self.django_setup()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 118, in django_setup

    django.setup()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup

    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate

    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create

    module = import_module(entry)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrapform'

Postgres is up - executing command

wait-for-it.sh: waiting for broker:6379 without a timeout

wait-for-it.sh: broker:6379 is available after 0 seconds

wait-for-it.sh: waiting for webapp:8000 without a timeout

wait-for-it.sh: webapp:8000 is available after 0 seconds

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>

    sys.exit(main())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main

    _main()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main

    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 495, in execute_from_commandline

    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline

    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 487, in handle_argv

    return self.execute(command, argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 415, in execute

    return cls(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 223, in run_from_argv

    return self(*args, **options)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 253, in __call__

    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 253, in run

    worker = self.app.Worker(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 96, in __init__

    self.app.loader.init_worker()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 114, in init_worker

    self.import_default_modules()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 108, in import_default_modules

    raise response

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 288, in send

    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 84, in on_import_modules

    self.worker_fixup.validate_models()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 122, in validate_models

    self.django_setup()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 118, in django_setup

    django.setup()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup

    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate

    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create

    module = import_module(entry)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrapform'
```

Here is the celery.py code, my project is named as project.

```
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.conf.result_backend_transport_options = {
    'retry_policy': {
       'timeout': 5.0
    }
}

app.autodiscover_tasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

What could be it? Thanks people.

Comment: Where have you installed all the necessary packages for your app, in a virtual env or in the global install of Python3.9?

Comment: I have created a container and install all packages on global.